# Buling REST with spring-mvc returns 404 The origin server did not find a current

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to build rest api with spring mvc and maven web project; however, when I try to run it on server it returns 404 on any url.

> "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

I've tried to find the solution on the internet and none of them worked for me. I think there might be some mistakes in my configuration but I don't know what. The project is build on eclipse using maven web project, using spring-mvc and hibernate with database mysql. I am kind of confused because there is no error in the log.

Below is my **web.xml** that I put inside ***src/main/webapp/WEB-INF***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/com/test/restlearning/applicationContext/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

Below is my **applicationContext.xml** that I put inside **src/main/resources/com/test/restlearning/applicationContext**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation=" 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-5.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-5.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-5.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.restlearning.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean> 
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restlearning" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" /> 
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test.restlearning.dto"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="personDao" class="com.test.restlearning.dao.impl.PersonDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>


<bean id="personService" class="com.test.restlearning.service.impl.PersonServiceImpl">
    <consrtuctor-arg ref="personDao" />
</bean>
```

and below is one of my controller

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/persons") 
public class PersonController {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("personService")
private PersonService personService;

@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public Object getAll(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        List<Person> persons = personService.getAll();
        String url = ServletUtil.unwrap(request);
        String json = PersonJSONWrapper.wrap(persons,url);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
    }
}

public static String getURL() {
    return "/persons";
}

public static String getURL(Integer id) {
    return "/persons"+id.toString();
}

}
```

I would be glad if you could point out my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no bean *PersonService* in application context. Add *PersonService* class to *applicationContext.xml* as bean.

Comment: I've tried to add @Qualifier("personService") below the autowired annotation. But I still got the some problem

Comment: Just add this bean to xml.